# Do I use "for" or "of" or "to?"

Tags: prepositions, usage

Which sentence should I use?

> I learned about the techniques **of** creating an AD.

> I learned about the techniques **for** creating an AD.

> I learned about the techniques **to** create an AD.

Comment: Not central to your question, but... what's an "AD"? If you mean an abbreviation for "advertisement," it should be lowercase, "ad."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, use "for" (and sometimes "to") when you want to talk about a sense of **direction or purpose**.
For example: I am going home for dinner (to eat). I am driving slowly for safety (to be safe). I am watching for trouble.

By contrast, use "of" when you want to talk about a sense of **belonging or ownership**.
For example: I watch the edge of the road. I see the outline of the trees. I don't stare at the lights of the oncoming traffic.

In your case, I think that "for" is more appropriate, because I think that the techniques have a *purpose* which is creating an AD, more than I think the techniques *belong* to the creation process. However, this is a subtle issue and I wouldn't be surprised if people disagree with me. On balance, I don't think you will surprise many people whichever word you use.

Answer (score 1):

"techniques **for**" doing something definitely sounds the most idiomatic to me.

Additionally, depending on context and what an AD is, it might sound more natural to omit the definite article. If this is the first sentence mentioning techniques, "the techniques" suggests there is an exclusive set of necessary steps, rather than several strategies that happen to be useful.